# Broaden the scope of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written some jQuery functions to resize images, keeping their aspect ratio on pageload, and window resize. These functions work great, but I built them specifically for one scenario. Now, another similar scenario has arisen in which I must do nearly the same functionality, only with iFrames. In the interest of becoming a better coder, and not adding extra code how can I concisely and efficiently re-use these functions for iFrames across the site, as well as the `$('.com-background > img')` scenario?

Here is the jQuery:

```
function imageCalc() {
    $imgWidth = $('.com-background > img').width();
    $imgHeight = $('.com-background > img').height();
    $imgAspectRatio =  $imgHeight / $imgWidth;
    $('.com-background > img').css('margin-left', '-10px' );

}
function setImageDims() {
    $('.com-background > img').css('height', function( calcHeight ) { return $imgAspectRatio * $('#main-content').width(); });
    $('.com-background > img').css('width', function( calcWidth ) { return $('#main-content').width() + 20; }); 
}

function imageResize() {
    $('.com-background > img').css('width', function( resizeWidth ) { return $("body").width() });
    $('.com-background > img').css('height', function( resizeHeight ) { return $imgAspectRatio * $('.com-background > img').width();  });
}
```

Comment: Update the functions to take the selector as an argument instead of hard-coding it? (Also, unrelated to your question, cache your jQuery objects, don't keep re-selecting the same  elements within the same function.)

Comment: Could you structure the code as an example as an answer below, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @nnnnnn from the comments means is :

> Update the functions to take the selector as an argument instead of
>   hard-coding it?

Turn this :

```
function imageCalc() {
    $imgWidth = $('.com-background > img').width();
    $imgHeight = $('.com-background > img').height();
    $imgAspectRatio =  $imgHeight / $imgWidth;
    $('.com-background > img').css('margin-left', '-10px' );

}
```

To this :

```
//where selector is your string query
function imageCalc(selector) {
    $imgWidth = $(selector).width();
    $imgHeight = $(selector).height();
    $imgAspectRatio =  $imgHeight / $imgWidth;
    $(selector).css('margin-left', '-10px' );

}
```

The above changes would make your functions *generic*, in the sense that you can do the same to other DOM objects as long as you specify what to change via the **selector** argument. To do the same thing you're doing right now, you have to call `imageCalc('.com-background > img');`, and so on.

And by this,

> Also, unrelated to your question, cache your jQuery objects, don't
>   keep re-selecting the same elements within the same function

he means :

```
//where selector is your string query
function imageCalc(selector) {
    var obj=$(selector);
    $imgWidth = obj.width();
    $imgHeight = obj.height();
    $imgAspectRatio =  $imgHeight / $imgWidth;
    obj.css('margin-left', '-10px' );

}
```

What this does is *cache* your object, which means you just locate it one time, and reuse that same object. It makes a difference in the performance, because everytime you use `$(selector)`, you're re-searching the DOM tree to find that one element, which does take time.

Comment: +1. Yep, that's what I meant. Note also, Chris, that all variables should be declared with `var` (like the `obj` variable in this answer), otherwise they'll be global variables.